# Element type is invalid: .Check render method

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

The following error occurred after using react-router-dom:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports. Check the render method of `CustomNavbar`.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router ,Route } from 'react-router-dom' ;
import Home from './components/Home' ;
import Company from './components/Company' ;
import News from './components/News' ;
import Services from './components/Services' ;
import Contact from './components/Contact' ;
import Partners from './components/Partners' ;
import Navbar from './components/CustomNavbar' ;


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router> 
       <div>
         <Navbar />
        <Route exact path ="/" component ={Home} />
        <Route path ="/company" component ={Company} />
        <Route path ="/services" component ={Services} />
        <Route path ="/partners" component ={Partners} />
        <Route path ="/news" component ={News} />
        <Route path ="/contact" component ={Contact} />
       </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

CustomNavbar.jsx:

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router ,Route } from 'react-router-dom' ;
import Home from './components/Home' ;
import Company from './components/Company' ;
import News from './components/News' ;
import Services from './components/Services' ;
import Contact from './components/Contact' ;
import Partners from './components/Partners' ;
import Navbar from './components/CustomNavbar' ;


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router> 
       <div>
         <Navbar />
        <Route exact path ="/" component ={Home} />
        <Route path ="/company" component ={Company} />
        <Route path ="/services" component ={Services} />
        <Route path ="/partners" component ={Partners} />
        <Route path ="/news" component ={News} />
        <Route path ="/contact" component ={Contact} />
       </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;

Index.js :

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { BrowserRouter as Router ,Route } from 'react-router-dom' ;
import Home from './components/Home' ;
import Company from './components/Company' ;
import News from './components/News' ;
import Services from './components/Services' ;
import Contact from './components/Contact' ;
import Partners from './components/Partners' ;
import Navbar from './components/CustomNavbar' ;


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router> 
       <div>
         <Navbar />
        <Route exact path ="/" component ={Home} />
        <Route path ="/company" component ={Company} />
        <Route path ="/services" component ={Services} />
        <Route path ="/partners" component ={Partners} />
        <Route path ="/news" component ={News} />
        <Route path ="/contact" component ={Contact} />
       </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What does your CustomNavbar component code look like? Sounds like you forgot to export it.

Comment: Why have you included the same piece of code 3 times?